# Google has indexed urls like www.example/folder/?SD what are these?

Tags: url, indexing, parameters, search-engine, google-search-console

In the google search console's list of indexed pages for my site there are many urls like this:

https://www.stakeholdermap.com/project-templates/change-management-plan-pdf/?SD

https://www.stakeholdermap.com/project-templates/_notes/?SD

https://www.stakeholdermap.com/plan-project/images/?SA

These aren't real pages and I have made sure they go to my custom error page. I am just wondering what they are? That is, what is google seeing that it wants to index?

Comment: Query parameters are often used in web applications to pass data to the server for processing. In some cases, these parameters may be used for tracking or session management. Let's check where they come from. I recommend you check where they come from. Log into Google Search Console, take one of these links and drop it into Google Inspect URL. There, opposite the referring page, you will see where they were found. Then you can find them in the code and stop their generation.

Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/ATC0P0H.png

Comment: Thanks Maniac. The referring urls are more of the same. 
Sitemaps
No referring sitemaps detected
Referring page
https://www.stakeholdermap.com/plan-project/images/
https://www.stakeholdermap.com/plan-project/images/?C=D;O=D

Comment: I couldn't check it for you because stakeholdermap.com/plan-project/images no longer exists. Would you find another indexed page?